# JavaFX position dialog and stage in center of screen

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

The following codes demonstrates centering of a dialog and the stage in the center of the screen. The dialog is supposed to be displayed first for the user to enter the login credentials. After successful login, the main window (stage) is then displayed. I found the solution of centering the dialog and stage from this web site, but it doesn't seem very ideal. For both the dialog and stage, they have to be displayed first before we can calculate the coordinates and then positioning them in the center. This means that we can see the dialog and the main window moving to the center after they are displayed. Is there a better way? Ideally, they should be positioned in the center before they are displayed.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;

public class Demo extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Dialog<String> dialog;
    private Button createUserButton = new Button("Create User");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        Text usersLabel = new Text("Current Users:");
        TableColumn<User, String> indexColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("No.");
        indexColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 10);
        indexColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().indexProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> userNameColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("User Name");
        userNameColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 60);
        userNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().userNameProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> roleColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("Role");
        roleColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 30);
        roleColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().roleProperty());
        TableView<User> tableView = new TableView<User>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(indexColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(userNameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(roleColumn);
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        Text dummyLabel = new Text("");
        VBox leftPane = new VBox(5);
        leftPane.getChildren().addAll(usersLabel, tableView);
        VBox rightPane = new VBox(20);
        rightPane.setFillWidth(true);
        rightPane.getChildren().addAll(dummyLabel, createUserButton);
        GridPane mainPane = new GridPane();
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        mainPane.setHgap(20);
        mainPane.add(leftPane, 0, 0);
        mainPane.add(rightPane, 1, 0);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        showDialog();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Please enter User Name and Password to login.");
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        Label userNameLabel = new Label("User Name:");
        Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password:");
        TextField userNameField = new TextField();
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 35, 20, 35));
        grid.add(userNameLabel, 1, 1);
        grid.add(userNameField, 2, 1);
        grid.add(passwordLabel, 1, 2);
        grid.add(passwordField, 2, 2);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
        okButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            createUser(userNameField.getText().trim(), passwordField.getText());
            event.consume();
        });
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
            Window window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
            window.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - window.getWidth()) / 2);
            window.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - window.getHeight()) / 2);
        });
        dialog.showAndWait();
    }

    private void createUser(String userName, String password) {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(true);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                }
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            Boolean success = task.getValue();
            dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(false);
            dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            if (success.booleanValue()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    dialog.close();
                    primaryStage.show();
                    Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
                    primaryStage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - primaryStage.getWidth()) / 2);
                    primaryStage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - primaryStage.getHeight()) / 2);
                });
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Login Error");
                alert.setHeaderText("Unable to login.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Application.launch(arguments);
    }

}

class User {

    private StringProperty index;

    private StringProperty userName;

    private StringProperty role;

    public String getIndex() {
        return indexProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty indexProperty() {
        if (index == null) {
            index = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "index");
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(String index) {
        indexProperty().set(index);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty userNameProperty() {
        if (userName == null) {
            userName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "userName");
        }
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        userNameProperty().set(userName);
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return roleProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty roleProperty() {
        if (role == null) {
            role = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "role");
        }
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        roleProperty().set(role);
    }

}
```

Below is solution by setting custom dimensions to stage and dialog. It works for the stage but it doesn't work for the dialog.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class Demo extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Dialog<String> dialog;
    private Button createUserButton = new Button("Create User");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        Text usersLabel = new Text("Current Users:");
        TableColumn<User, String> indexColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("No.");
        indexColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 10);
        indexColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().indexProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> userNameColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("User Name");
        userNameColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 60);
        userNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().userNameProperty());
        TableColumn<User, String> roleColumn = new TableColumn<User, String>("Role");
        roleColumn.setMaxWidth(1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 30);
        roleColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> p.getValue().roleProperty());
        TableView<User> tableView = new TableView<User>();
        tableView.getColumns().add(indexColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(userNameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(roleColumn);
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        Text dummyLabel = new Text("");
        VBox leftPane = new VBox(5);
        leftPane.getChildren().addAll(usersLabel, tableView);
        VBox rightPane = new VBox(20);
        rightPane.setFillWidth(true);
        rightPane.getChildren().addAll(dummyLabel, createUserButton);
        GridPane mainPane = new GridPane();
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        mainPane.setHgap(20);
        mainPane.add(leftPane, 0, 0);
        mainPane.add(rightPane, 1, 0);
        float width = 372f;
        float height = 470f;
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, width, height);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        primaryStage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - width) / 2);
        primaryStage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - height) / 2);
        showDialog();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Login");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Please enter User Name and Password to login.");
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        Label userNameLabel = new Label("User Name:");
        Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password:");
        TextField userNameField = new TextField();
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 35, 20, 35));
        grid.add(userNameLabel, 1, 1);
        grid.add(userNameField, 2, 1);
        grid.add(passwordLabel, 1, 2);
        grid.add(passwordField, 2, 2);
        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
        okButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            login(userNameField.getText().trim(), passwordField.getText());
            event.consume();
        });
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        float width = 509f;
        float height = 168f;
        dialog.setWidth(width);
        dialog.setHeight(height);
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        dialog.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - width) / 2);
        dialog.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - height) / 2);
        dialog.showAndWait();
    }

    private void login(String userName, String password) {
        dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(true);
        dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
        Task<Boolean> task = new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                }
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            Boolean success = task.getValue();
            dialog.getDialogPane().setDisable(false);
            dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            if (success.booleanValue()) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    primaryStage.show();
                });
            } else {
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setTitle("Login Error");
                alert.setHeaderText("Unable to login.");
                alert.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Application.launch(arguments);
    }

}

class User {

    private StringProperty index;

    private StringProperty userName;

    private StringProperty role;

    public String getIndex() {
        return indexProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty indexProperty() {
        if (index == null) {
            index = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "index");
        }
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(String index) {
        indexProperty().set(index);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userNameProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty userNameProperty() {
        if (userName == null) {
            userName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "userName");
        }
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        userNameProperty().set(userName);
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return roleProperty().get();
    }

    public StringProperty roleProperty() {
        if (role == null) {
            role = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "role");
        }
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        roleProperty().set(role);
    }

}
```

JKostikiadis's solution:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {

    private static final double WIDTH = 316.0;
    private static final double HEIGHT = 339.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        HBox pane = new HBox();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button b = new Button("click me");
        b.setOnAction(e -> {
            showDialog();
        });

        pane.getChildren().add(b);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        centerStage(stage, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        stage.show();


    }

    private void showDialog() {
        Alert dialog = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        dialog.setTitle("Error Dialog");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Look, an Error Dialog");
        dialog.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!\nOoops, there was an error!");

        Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
        centerStage(stage, -10000, -10000);
        dialog.show();
        System.out.println(stage.getWidth() + " " + stage.getHeight());
        dialog.hide();
        centerStage(stage, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());        
        dialog.showAndWait();

    }

    private void centerStage(Stage stage, double width, double height) {
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        stage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - width) / 2);
        stage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - height) / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe i need some coffee to wake up, but isn't by default the location of the Dialogs and Stages show up on the center of screen? just remove your code with "Platform.runLater(()-> .." and inside the "if (success.booleanValue()) {" about getting the primary stage location etc and run again. Well if you have more than 1 monitor I would understand your logic but I can't see say something about that in your post.

Comment: No, by default they are not on the center of the screen. Horizontally they are in the center, by vertically they are slightly higher up. I'm using just one monitor by the way.

Comment: Well it must be so relevant that i haven't notice it :P. Anyway the primaryStage will take it's dimensions ( width, height ) you the.show() or .showAndWait() method is called. So getting the primaryStage.getWith() or height() before that it's not going to work. So i would suggest to set it's default width and height like width= 500, height=600; and set the location before you show the stage ( or dialog ). If you want to use the exact width and height of your stage then their are : 372.0 - 470.0 :P

Comment: Also, I notice that horizontally, the dialog is by default not in the center of the stage (I make both of them appear at the same time). So it could be that one is already in the center horizontally, but not the other. Vertically, both are not in the center by default.

Comment: JKostikiadis, I know I could have set the dimensions of the dialog and stage myself. But it doesn't seem like a good idea. If the monitor setting is different, or if I were to change the widgets' styles, the dialog and stage may end up ugly.

Comment: Hmm i can't see the problem by having two constants holding the app application, unless the monitor size is too small there is not going to be any problem but if you want to make a responsible layout appearance you will have to check the dimensions of the monitor before setting the size of the stage and apply different sizes depending on the screen inches, at least that's the way I know people doing it (of course if you want to eliminate the stage movement effect ). Maybe there is another way but I don't think so just way for someone else to replay.

Comment: @JKostikiadis: I hadn't noticed before either, but the user is [right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603948/javafx-position-dialog-and-stage-in-center-of-screen#comment80161189_46603948); as seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/stage/Window.java#218), the _X_ center is 1/2, but the _Y_ center is 1/3.

Comment: For custom stage and dialog, I can set their dimensions myself. But for alerts, how would that be possible? Surely the alert dialog dimension will change according to the length of the message.

Comment: I am guessing when the program first loads you can keep you `Stage` invisible. While the `Stage` is invisible get the Screens dimensions. Adjust your `Stage` accordingly. Finally, set the `Stage` to visible

Comment: Hi Sedrick, that won't work. Before the stage is displayed, if we call primaryStage.getX() and primaryStage.getY(), they both return NaN. Getting the screen's dimension should be fine, but without the stage's dimension, I won't be able to calculate the center's coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say primaryStage.getWidth() and primaryStage.getHeight() above.

Comment: @JKostikiadis, as you suggested, I set custom dimensions to the stage and dialog (see my new codes above). It works for the stage, but it doesn't work for the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well because you ask me in the commends I am going to provide an example of setting the Stage ( main application or dialog ) to the center of the screen by early initialization of their dimensions.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {

    private static final double WIDTH = 316.0;
    private static final double HEIGHT = 339.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        HBox pane = new HBox();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Button b = new Button("click me");
        b.setOnAction(e -> {
            showDialog();
        });

        pane.getChildren().add(b);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        centerStage(stage, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        stage.show();

        System.out.println(stage.getWidth() + " " + stage.getHeight());
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        Alert dialog = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        dialog.setTitle("Error Dialog");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Look, an Error Dialog");
        dialog.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!");

        Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
        centerStage(stage, 366, 175);

        dialog.showAndWait();

    }

    private void centerStage(Stage stage, double width, double height) {
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        stage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - width) / 2);
        stage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - height) / 2);
    }
}
```

In the example above you will see that I have specify the application dimensions to 300,300 but I am using for width = 316.0 and height = 339.0 and you might wondering why. It's because the stage size will always be a little bigger than the Scene ( borders + Title bar etc ) so in order to find the real width and height of the Stage you will have to print the dimensions of the stage after you show it. The same logic is happening to the Dialog.

Important : Of course you could forget all about the above and just do :

```
stage.setWidth(300); // or a variable here 
stage.setHeight(300);
```

But this will affect your internal components cause if previously the scene's components had a size of 300,300 now they are going to be squeezed to something less in order to make the stage to fix the size of 300,300 so in that case yes it might affect the way your application looks like.

In the past I was searching for a way to find the dimension of a label before I show it. I found out that it was possible to get it's dimensions by adding it to the Scene and then call

```
labe.impl_processCSS(true);
System.out.println(labe.prefWidth(-1) + "/" + labe.prefHeight(-1));
```

Now If I try to do the same for the main pane in the above application it shows 59/25 which are the dimensions of the button itself so this approach  is not going to work in case of someone wondering about it.

**Edit** :

I don't really want to show this "hack" cause I find it stupid and i am sure there is a better way, but until I find it here you go :

```
private void showDialog() {
    Alert dialog = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    dialog.setTitle("Error Dialog");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Look, an Error Dialog");
    dialog.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!\nOoops, there was an error!");

    Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    centerStage(stage, -10000, -10000);
    dialog.show();
    centerStage(stage, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());   
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but the problem is that when the dialog's header or content text changes, the dialog's dimension will change as well. Usually the dialog's body text is determined dynamically, so I won't be able to know the exact dialog's dimension beforehand.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point, I have update my answer with a 'hack' well it's not something I am proud of but it's definitely going to work.

Comment: Hi JKostikiadis, I used your "hack" now. See the codes posted in my original post. The dialog is horizontally in the center now, but somehow it is not center vertically. I can't find any problem with the codes. Very strange why vertically it is still not right.

Comment: Do be honest i was sure that by hiding and showing again will not change anything but for some reason does.. So in order to be able to fix it just show the window once in a hidden location and then apply the new layout ( transformation ) and you will be fine, check my edit code

Comment: @user3573403 Oh and in case you didn't notice it the same logic can be applied to the main stage of the application too. You don't need to know or specify the dimensions from the start, just show the window to a unwatchable location ( -x,-y) and then relocate the entire application to the center using the same method like the dialog.

Comment: Hi JKostikiadis, did you see my previous comment? Your "hack" works partially only. See your solution in my original post. Horizontally the dialog is centered, but vertically it is still not. It's quite puzzling to me.

Comment: @User3573403 Yes i did, did you saw mine previous comment? I made a change in my edited code. Apparently hiding and showing again the stage is not working so you need to remove the hide and just show the stage only once and only relocate it, check again my code above and tell me if you have any problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156354/discussion-between-jkostikiadis-and-user3573403).

Comment: Hi JKostikiadis, now your codes work. I need to use showAndWait() instead of show() as I want a blocking dialog. I wouldn't be able to make the second call to centerStage() if I use showAndWait() since I have to wait for the latter's return. Therefore, I had to put the second call to centerStage() before showAndWait(), and enclose centerStage() with Platform.runLater().

Comment: OK, I finally got everything to work with your solution. Thanks JKostikiadis!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you have to wait for the width/height of the `Window` (or `Dialog`) to be computed as well as for the `Window` to be shown. Since the `Window` is visible you will always notice the window moving when updating the xy-position.

Doing the update when the `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` event is fired might provide a better result:

```
   final Window window = dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();

    window.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
            window.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - window.getWidth()) / 2);
            window.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - window.getHeight()) / 2);

        }
    });
```

And for the primaryStage

```
    primaryStage.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        primaryStage.setX((screenBounds.getWidth() - primaryStage.getWidth()) / 2);
        primaryStage.setY((screenBounds.getHeight() - primaryStage.getHeight()) / 2);
    }
});
primaryStage.show();
```

But as mentioned by JKostikiadis, a better and proper solution might be to compute your own dimension with respect to the current screen size.

Here is the small improvement I can see.
When running your demo on my machine, the movement is erratic:

[image]

I can see a small improvement when using `WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN` (without using`Platform.runLater` for the first Dialog):

[image]

Anyway, I don't think using `Platform.runLater` for displaying the first window is ideal as there is no guarantee that `showAndWait()` will always be executed before the `Runnable`

Comment: Your solution doesn't really seem to make any difference.

Comment: I can set my own dimensions to stages and dialogs, but it doesn't seem possible to do so for alerts. For alerts, their dimensions vary according to the body messages that I send to them, right?

Comment: Also, you can specify the preferred width/height of the alert's  DialogPane: ``alert.getDialogPane().setPrefWidth(400)``

Comment: Hi shaka-b, I set custom dimensions to the stage and dialog (see my new codes above). It works for the stage but it doesn't work for the dialog.

Comment: Try `dialog.getDialogPane().setPrefWidth(width)`

Answer (score 1):

You can center a stage on another stage before rendering it by applying the css which will provide you with the width/height.

For example.

From where you create the stage:

```
WindowHelper.centerChildWindowOnStage(stage, primaryStage);  //assuming primary is the stage you want to center on
stage.show();
```

below is the code to center the unshown window (assume this is on a WindowHelper class to be reused in the app).

```
public static void centerChildWindowOnStage(Stage stage, Stage primaryStage ) {

    if(primaryStage == null){
        return;
    }

    double x = stage.getX();
    double y = stage.getY();

    // Firstly we need to force CSS and layout to happen, as the dialogPane
    // may not have been shown yet (so it has no dimensions)
    stage.getScene().getRoot().applyCss();
    stage.getScene().getRoot().layout();

    final Scene ownerScene = primaryStage.getScene();
    final double titleBarHeight = ownerScene.getY();

    // because Stage does not seem to centre itself over its owner, we
    // do it here.

    // then we can get the dimensions and position the dialog appropriately.
    final double dialogWidth = stage.getScene().getRoot().prefWidth(-1);
    final double dialogHeight = stage.getScene().getRoot().prefHeight(dialogWidth);

    final double ownerWidth = primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().prefWidth(-1);
    final double ownerHeight = primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().prefHeight(ownerWidth);

    if(dialogWidth < ownerWidth){
        x = primaryStage.getX() + (ownerScene.getWidth() / 2.0) - (dialogWidth / 2.0);
    }else {
        x = primaryStage.getX();
        stage.setWidth(dialogWidth);
    }

    if(dialogHeight < ownerHeight){
        y = primaryStage.getY() + titleBarHeight / 2.0 + (ownerScene.getHeight() / 2.0) - (dialogHeight / 2.0);
    }else {
        y = primaryStage.getY();
    }

    stage.setX(x);
    stage.setY(y);
}
```